# How to construct scope variables dynamically in angular view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose, I have :

```
$scope.head1="abc";
$scope.head2="bfc";
...
...
$scope.head12="bfc";
```

and, I do this :

```
<div ng-repeat="count in [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]" class="padding-top-10">
  <span>{{head + count}}</span>
</div>
```

I want to get the values of head1, head2, head3.. head12 in the div. How to do that ?

Comment: can't you create an array with the values of `head1` `head2` etc and simply display the values in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
<div ng-repeat="count in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]" class="padding-top-10">
       <span>{{$parent['head'+count]}}</span>
   </div>
</body>
```

Like this you do not need an extra scope function to get the values from your scope variables.
$parent is necessary because your ng-repeat creates its own scope.

angular docs-->
ngRepeat
- directive in module ng
The ngRepeat directive instantiates a template once per item from a collection. Each template instance gets its own scope,

Answer (score 3):

Any reason you're not doing this?

```
$scope.head = ["abc", "bfc", ..., "bfc"];
```

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="count in [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]" class="padding-top-10">
  <span>{{ head[count - 1] }}</span>
</div>
```

---

If that's not an option, you can define this method:

```
$scope.getHead = function (num) {
    return $scope["head" + num];
};
```

And then:

```
<div ng-repeat="count in [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]" class="padding-top-10">
  <span>{{ getHead(count) }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [property accessor bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) with the `this` context keyword:

```
<div ng-repeat="count in [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]" class="padding-top-10">
  <span>{{this["head"+count]}}</span>
</div>
```

With [Angular Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) the `this` keyword evaluates to the $scope of the expression.

Be aware that the `ng-repeat` directive creates child scopes and that `this` expression finds the value by prototypical inheritance. This can cause problems when using `this` in `ng-model` directives. (This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of [always have a '.' in your ng-models](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m))

For more information, see [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs).